# Searching for a particular value then pasting into another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Let me give you a basic understanding of my what I'm trying to do. I have two workbooks: Master Workbook and Workbook A. Information in Workbook A will be inputted into the Master Workbook. In Workbook A, there is Column X with numbers between the ranges of 1 to 25. All I care about are values greater than 14.

Problem: How do I create a VBA function that looks at Column X (Row 1) to see if it is greater than 14? If it is then it copies the entire row and pastes it into the Master Workbook, else it moves onto Column X2. Also, after copying row 1 and pasting into Master Workbook, I also need it to go back to Workbook A and check the rest of Column X if it is greater 14.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do this in VBA? Adding a filter to Column X and using it to hide rows with values <= 14 seems pretty easy to do without any code.

Comment: Matt I completely agree, but for this exercise I have to create a final report that does this without using the advanced filter option. Would be much easier if I could filter it though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
Private Sub checkAndCopy()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim foundItem As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim pasteTo As Range
Dim k As Integer

k = 0

lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

For i = 1 To lastRow
   If Cells(i, 24).Value > 14 Then
      k = k + 1
      For j = 1 To 24
         foundItem = Cells(i, j).Value
         Set pasteTo = Workbook(yourWorkbook).Cells(k, j)
         pasteTo.Value = foundItem
      Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Note that it copies into the new workbook starting on Row 1.  You can have it search for the next empty line and add to that by including:

```
k = Workbook(yourWorkbook).WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: sorry this is such a newb question, for "Workbook(yourWorkbook)" if my excel doc is called "Overall Compilation.xlsx" and the tab that I'm pasting into is called "Annual Figures" what do I put for "Workbook(yourWorkbook)"

Comment: You can call it by filename, like Workbooks("Y:\My Documents\Master Workbook.xls").  If it's not already open in Excel, you should use Workbooks(your path here).Open to load it, then run the FOR loops, and then use Workbooks(your workbook name here).Save to save it.  You can then close the master programatically using Workbooks(your workbook name).Close.  Here's the entry on the Microsoft site about the Workbook object.  Hopefully that will help you if you run into syntax questions.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224504%28v=office.11%29.aspx